# How to filter data by dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data in an excel that is ~1300 rows long. The dates are exported in a non-normal format so I had to split them and one of the columns doesn't always have a date as the ticket isn't closed out. I have been able to split the dates and make the empty cells being whatever the current date is so I can get lifetime data for my tickets.

The issue however is I want to be able to filter out based on a date. i.e. Only use everything that is greater than 11/9/2020.

My current code that is working

```
df3 = df1['ResolvedDate'].str.split('T').str[0]

df2 = df1['CreateDate'].str.split('T').str[0]

df3.loc[df3.isnull()] = datetime.now()

create_date = pd.to_datetime(df2)
resolved_date = pd.to_datetime(df3)

df9 = resolved_date - create_date
```

To filter I've been trying to use (df is from using pd.dataframe to organize data for excel, not sure where I needed to put the filter but I've tried in multiple areas)

```
filtered = (df['ResolvedDate'] > datetime.date(2020, 11, 9))
Data = df.loc[filtered]
```

Error I'm getting

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

Ideally, the way the date filter would work would allow me to use tkinter to get user input.

Any help anyone can give me will be greatly appreciated

**Update**

I changed `df3.loc[df3.isnull()] = datetime.now()` to `df3.loc[df3.isnull()] = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` as I didn't realize the previous was also giving me the time when I only wanted the date. So now all the dates are uniform and there doesn't appear to be any differences but am still getting the following error when trying to filter.

`filtered = (df['ResolvedDate'] > datetime.date(2020, 11, 9))`

`TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object`

Comment: Provide a some rows of your data, including the problematic ones. Also, you've created _many_ dataframes `df2`, `df3`, `df9` and just `df`. Are you sure `df` is correct in `df['ResolvedDate'] > datetime.date(2020, 11, 9)` ?

Comment: The only issue I'm having is filtering dates so it's not an issue of some of the dates are good and some aren't. All my dates are fine I just want to limit what dates are actually reported. And yes I am sure `df` is correct. As I stated in my post `df` is from a `pd.dataframe` specifying where each piece of data goes in the excel sheet with it's column name. So somewhere in my `df =pd.Dataframe` I have `ResolvedDate: df3` so to be able to pull the column of Resolved Dates `df['ResolvedDate']`.

Comment: Nathaniel check the type of the values in df['ResolvedDate'] you may have an unexpected type there.

Comment: It looks like `df3.loc[df3.isnull()] = datetime.now()` is inserting the date but it is also inserting the time.

It's coming out like this `2020-11-30 07:53:05` instead of `2020-11-30` as the rest of the dates are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. If I put it a start and end date it seems to be able to filter that way without giving me an error.

```
start_date = '2020-11-16'
end_date = '2020-12-2'

after_start_date = df['ResolvedDate'] >= start_date
before_end_date = df['ResolvedDate'] <= end_date
between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
Data = df.loc[between_two_dates]
```